# Getting GeoJSON file to load in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson, node-js

I have validated the JSON and I'm certain it is clean. I'm loading it from a web server (using Node.js).  The Firefox error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Chrome reports the unexpected character to be "<".

It appears that the payload from the call to JSON.parse is the application's index.html file rather than the data file, but I may be interpreting this wrong.

Am I missing something obvious?

I've stripped the code back to as simple as I can for now:

index.js

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';

//CONFIG
const initmapcenter = [-124.01901771596816, 54.018354087405754 ];
const dataurl = './data/SABoundarygeo.json';

// Polygons style
function polygonStyleFunction(feature, resolution) {
    return new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'blue',
        width: 1,
        }),
        fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)',
        }),
    });
}
// Vector layer from a GeoJson file url
var vectorPolygons = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSON(),
      url: dataurl
    })
    // , style: polygonStyleFunction
  });

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM()
    }),
    vectorPolygons
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat(initmapcenter),
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using Parcel with OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 80%;
        max-width: 1200px;
        height: 800px;
        margin:auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look in the browsers debugger network section and see what is the result of json file request.

Comment: make sure the json is accessible at the URL you have specified.

Comment: @TomazicM - The JSON file seems to be acquired successfully (code 200) but under XHR the payload for the JSON looks like the index.html instead of the json contents.  This would make the google error makes sense when it says it is seeing a "<" as the first character.

Comment: @JGH - yes it is.  It is local to the site under a data directory.  No cross-domain or permissions issues.

Comment: The two comments you wrote seems contradictory... (ex: return the default page if a resource / route / parameter is not found, return the default page for "exotic" extensions etc)

Comment: @JGH - yes it is contradictory.  Therefore my posting this in the first place.

.JSON is certainly not an "exotic" extrension (as often .geojson might be).  The data location is correct and relative to the site root, and the JSON file is validated (in fact it's proven in a production environment in two other use cases), both using Leaflet.  

In this case I'm using a NODE.JS environment for dev/test.

Comment: Again: have a look in the browsers debugger network section and see what is the result of json file request. If it's not your GeoJSON but something else, then this is server side/node.js problem.

Answer (score 0):

Having packaged the code and copied it to a production server it worked without issue.  I have to conclude that there is something about the Node environment that is preventing the loading of the JSON file.  I'll need to find an alternative configuration.

Thank you for your help.